# Working on many columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have many columns in my excel sheet and I am working on them extensively (Sorting, counting etc.).
However, it's a bit complicated, for instance, when I want to move to the last column from the first column because I have many columns. Is there a way to focus only on those 2 columns I want? Most of the time I am interested in a pair of columns. Can I easily bring those columns next to each other? For example, if there were a list of the columns, I could just tick/untick them. That would be one solution. But I suspect there is anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

righclick on the columns header you dont want to see, and click on hide.
If you want to see them again, again rightclick on the column and click on show again (dont know what the button is called in english)

Comment: Is there anything like a list to see the hidden columns becase when I click "unhide", it brings back all the columns.

Comment: if you hide column b and d, select column a and c and click on "unhide" then only column b will be shown again

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert the range to a Table (Insert ribbon, Table).  This means you can write formulas using Column Name references e.g. =[[@My Column]], not the standard column position references e.g. =A2.  These will survive any column re-ordering.

Tables have other benefits e.g. robust table references and automatically copying formulas as new rows are added.

Then you can safely move the columns around into any order that suits.  You can achieve this by Right-Clicking the entire column (or set of columns) and choosing Cut, then Right-Clicking an entire column where you want to move it to, and choosing Insert Cut Cells.